# BigQuery DataTransfer scheduleRuns Error

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api, data-transfer

I try to create projects.locations.transferConfigs/scheduleRuns

First i create transfer config. It works. But when i try to create scheduleRuns,i get error.

i get service
    $this->client = new Google_Client();
            $this->client->setAuthConfig( MCC_DIR . 'protected/config/client_secret_1.json');
            $this->client->setAccessType("offline");
            $this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
            $this->client->setScopes(array(
                    Google_Service_Bigquery::BIGQUERY,
                    Google_Service_Bigquery::CLOUD_PLATFORM,
                    Google_Service_Bigquery::CLOUD_PLATFORM_READ_ONLY
                )
            );
    $this->service = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer($this->client);

and i try to create tranfer and schedule

```
if (!$config_id = $this->getTransfer($adword_id))
            $config_id = $this->create($adword_id);
$params = new Google_Service_BigQueryDataTransfer_ScheduleTransferRunsRequest();
$params->setRangeStartTime("2017-08-17T00:00:00Z");
        $params->setRangeEndTime("2017-09-03T00:00:00Z");
        return $this->service->projects_locations_transferConfigs->scheduleRuns(
            'projects/' . self::PROJECT_ID . '/locations/europe/transferConfigs/' . $config_id,
            $params
        );
```

and on the try create schedule i get error

```
Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

May be need other scopes?

Comment: what API is this. Got a link?..

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/BigQueryDataTransfer